# General Python regex to extract dates (d,m,y) in different formats

Tags: python, regex, date, text-mining

I am looking for a way to extract dates (day, month, year) from a text. That is, I want to find all dates (or rather - as many as possible) in a human-written string.

Is there a Python regular expression covering as many possible formats as possible?

Comment:

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse
parse(s, fuzzy = True)
```

works fine but it is constrained to one date per one string.

Example:

> A program is taking place at sth from 21 January 2013 to 15th of February 2013.
>   Applications for funding will be accepted until April 15, 2012. Notification of acceptance : 1st Aug. or later. Early payment due: 15.10.12. etc. Late: 11/20/12.

Usually (but not always) convention is more-or-less consistent for a single entry.

It is easy to create an regex for a few cases, I can do that. The question is if there is already one collecting many different.

Comment: Regular expressions are not parsers.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Changed parse -> extract.

Comment: can you give us an example of the input?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to roll your own, you can take inspiration from the [Regexp::Common](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp%3a%3aCommon)'s [time](http://search.cpan.org/~roode/Regexp-Common-time-0.01/time.pm) module, and the patterns there for time and dates.

Be warned: [the code (direct link to it) is not trivial.](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ROODE/Regexp-Common-time-0.01/time.pm)

Comment: +1: Holy smokes, Batman! That is an excellent way to demonstrate this task is non-trivial. I especially like the documentation comments in the code - "*If the data are wildly variable,
such as raw user input, give up and use the L<Date::Manip> or
L<Date::Parse> module.*"

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with the module [`parsedatetime`](http://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/):

```
from parsedatetime import parsedatetime, parsedatetime_consts

pdt = parsedatetime.Calendar(parsedatetime_consts.Constants())
parsed, code = pdt.parse('''Your string''')
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants to *find* the dates before converting them.  Finding is the even harder part.